# Fatal error when using bold math and physics

Tags: physics, bm

I have a problem where writing \log in bold math `\bm{$\log$}` is resulting in a fatal error. I am using a multitude of packages, but I've narrowed it down to the physics package.

I get 10 errors when compiling a document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
It works fine in regular math mode
\begin{equation}
    \log(a/b)
\end{equation}
But when writing it in bold math, it doesn't work \bm{$\log(a/b)$} when physics is loaded.

\end{document}
```

Hopefully someone know how I can fix this, I can't really decode the error messages. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be `$\bm{\log(a/b)}$`, if you really want that. But I'd not be surprised if `physics` chokes with it.

Comment: Right now I've just used `\textbf{log}\bm{$(k_X/k_H)$}`, but I'd like to see if there is another solution

Comment: Why insisting on using `\bm` *outside* math mode?

Comment: @egreg Sadly `$\bm{\log(a/b)}$` doesn't work either, still produces a fatal error

Comment: @egreg I am convinced that that is the correct use of it, but I might be wrong. It doesn't produce any errors when I do it like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plainly said, `physics` and `bm` are not compatible with each other (and the blame is on the former).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\allbm}[1]{\begingroup\boldmath#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}

It works fine in regular math mode
\begin{equation}
    \log(a/b)
\end{equation}
But when writing it in bold math, it doesn't work \allbm{$\log(a/b)$} when physics is loaded.

\end{document}
```

Some comments: while `\bm{$<formula>$}` seems to work, it is wrong. It should be

```
$\bm{<formula>}$
```

On the other hand, `physics` redefines `\log` to do a complicated (and mostly useless) series of operations in order to automatically size parentheses. This makes the thing very fragile.

I'd avoid the package: in my opinion it offers nothing very advantageous.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've found an alternative for the `physics` package

Comment: @ChristianP. Don't tell me it's `commath`, please.